# Exchange data between java and php

Tags: java, php, netty, bungeecord

I am currently working on a web interface for my Minecraft server system. The web interface runs on PHP and the plugins of course on java.

I just need to find a secure way to exchange data between the Minecraft server and the HTTP server. In addition, the user should be able to execute commands in the web interface, which are then sent to the Minecraft server and executed.

Actually, I would like to stick to the Netty.io given by Spigot and Bungeecord, but I don't really see a way to include Netty.io in PHP.

Do any of you have an idea on how to solve my problem?
What alternatives are there? What can I do better How would one set up Netty.io on PHP?

Thanks a lot for your help,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to forward messages between servers and get an instant response (synchronously).
The most common solution is the [REST API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

Transfer requests over HTTP between servers.